# How to deactivate the session in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, linkedin-api

I am using 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git" gem to connect with linkedin. once i connect with linked in forwarded to my application the session maintains outside my application scope.

if i come out from my application and type www.linkedin.com than the logged in user information is seen in the browser.

My problem is:

Once the user logs in using my application the session should not be maintained outside the application scope and if the user types  www.linkedin.com he should not see his/her information.

Please help me how to do this in rails3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a `LinkedIn` feature.  Since the user has to `sign-in` in order to connect to your site and give your site permission to access its information, the `sign-in session cookie` is still kept alive by `LinkedIn`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Yes but there must be someway to find the cookie and kill that or rename it so that the problem does not continues.my question is how to find that using rails?.

Comment: I doubt your application would have access to the LinkedIn cookie.  
Do you know of any site that achieves this out of curiosity?

Comment: what i want is on what name the cookie is stored for linkedin?